# Web Element Groovy isSelected() and selected getting wrong result

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, groovy, katalon-studio

Scenario
I want to collect all the selected [checkbox - checked]  records in a table. Below is my method,

```
def getAlltheSelectedRecordId(String tableName){
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

        WebElement RefTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='${tableName}']/tbody"))

        List<WebElement> RowsOf_RefTable = RefTable.findElements(By.tagName('tr'))
        int Totalcount = RowsOf_RefTable.size()
        for (int row : (1..Totalcount)) {
            boolean isChecked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='${tableName}']/tbody/tr[' + row + ']/td[2]/input")).isSelected()
            println isChecked
            boolean isChecked1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='${tableName}']/tbody/tr[' + row + ']/td[2]/input")).selected
            println isChecked1
            if(isChecked){
                String selectedRecordID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='${tableName}']/tbody/tr[' + row + ']/td[5]/a")).getText()
                println selectedRecordID
            }           
        }
    }
```

Passing the table name as parameter and collect all the selected records in the table. But unfortunately always `isChecked` and `isChecked1` return `false`

Please guide me where is the problem

Comment: At first glance i'd say your quotes around ' + row + ' are wrong (use `"`) instad.  Or rahter directly use `${row}` instead of banging strings togehter with `+` (assuming this is the intention here)

Comment: thanks changing the single quote in to double quote its working

Comment: Not relevatn for the answer, but for nitpicks sake: don't use vars starting with uppercase letters (`RefTable` -> `refTable`) - it's against the styleguide and there are cases where the groovy compiler can thing you mean a class. Also you could reuse `RefTable` for the later element searches.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the way, the strings are put together and the problem is already visible with the syntax highlighting here in SO:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='${tableName}']/tbody/tr[' + row + ']/td[2]/input")
```

`"...' + row + '..."` does not put the value of `row` inside the string -- only this exact "code".

The solution is to use the proper quotes to end the string:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='${tableName}']/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td[2]/input")
```

Or even better, stick to the scheme already started in the beginning of the string: use Groovys string replacment:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='${tableName}']/tbody/tr[${row}]/td[2]/input")
```